# Concatenation only works when it feels like it?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to get the following code to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool prime_test(int num);
void stringRotation(string& str);

int main()
{
    vector<string> primes;
    ifstream infile("PRIMES1T.txt");

    // checks to see if there was any problems opening the .txt
    if (infile.is_open()) {
        string line = "";
        while(getline(infile,line)) {
            primes.push_back(line);
        }

        // rotates our string and tests if the number is still prime
        vector<string> primes2;
        for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {
            string str = primes[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
                stringRotation(str);
                int value = atoi(str.c_str());
                if (prime_test(value) == false) {
                    break;
                }
                if (j == str.length()-1) {
                    if (prime_test(value) == true) {
                        primes2.push_back(primes[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "There are " << primes2.size() << " primes that work.";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "File failed to open." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

// tests to see if num is a prime number
bool prime_test(int num) {
    if (num == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    // Finds first integer value larger than the sqrt of num
    // since that is all we really need.
    double dnum = num;
    double sqrt_dnum = sqrt(dnum);
    int counter = ceil(sqrt_dnum);

    for (int i = 2; i < counter; i++) {
        if (num == 2) {
            break;
        }
        if (num%i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// rotates a string
void stringRotation(string& str) {
    int len = str.length();

    // converts a char variable into a string variable
    stringstream ss;
    string ch;
    char c = str.at(0);
    ss << c;
    ss >> ch;

    str = str.substr(1,str.length());
    str = str.append(ch);
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

What it does is it takes a prime number say 999983, cuts off the first digit 9, and then adds it to the end of the rest of the number so that it spits out the new number 999839. It then tests whether or not this new number is prime or not and repeats the process until the original number is returned. If the number is prime every time we do this process, then we add that number to the vector primes2.

The problem I have is that the stringRotation function does not work properly for some reason. I have tested it by trying to outputting the string before adding the digit that was removed and outputting the string after adding the digit. It does not concatenate properly. It will cut off the first digit in 999983 so that we have str = '99983' and ch = '9' but then when I do str.append(ch), it still gives me 99983. I have also tried variations like str = str.append(ch) and str = str + ch.

I have tried copying just the function over to a different .cpp file to compile only adding a declaration for str by setting str to "999983" and it works fine.

**EDIT**
I changed stringRotation to:

```
void stringRotation(string& str) {
    int len = str.length();
    char ch = str.at(0);

    cout << ch << endl;

    str = str.substr(1,str.length());
    str.append(1,ch);
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

but the problem still persists. I have also tried string.push_back(ch) with no luck.

Comment: There is a `std::rotate` function.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The function stringRotation by itself works properly but when I try to run it with everything else, it stops working.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I will look into the rotate function. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: change `primes.push_back(line);` to `primes.push_back("999983");`  . If the problem goes away it means that the problem is with the contents of your file, not with your code

Comment: I am on a mac osx yosemite and I am compiling with terminal using g++ main.cc -o main

Comment: @A.Wong - Live example:  http://ideone.com/ZGngk7

Comment: @MattMcNabb AHH! It is the file. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps your file contains different line endings than g++ is expecting, your strings might have a stray `\n` or `'\r'` on the end, so the rotate function moves that character to the start. After reading a string, output the string and the string's `.size()` to check that it is not containing any bogus character on the end (or hexdump the string)

Comment: As MattMcNabb said, stringRotation works fine with *proper* strings. I can see the you never cleanup input for possible non printable characters (spaces, tabs, ...). You could try to convert line to an int, convert back to a string and use that cleaned string.

Comment: Hmm. You are right. There is an extra character at the end. 999983 has 6 digits but it says the size is 7.

Comment: I will do as Serge Ballesta suggested. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your programmer career, you will need to always make sure that your input is handled well. If you are loading data from a file which is not guaranteed to have a specific content scheme, you will always need to make sure that you prepare your data before parsing. In this particular case you need to make sure that your "numbers" are indeed numbers and execute your `stringRotation` on values which are guaranteed to be numbers.